# elasticsearch aggregation on field containing spaces

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field that contains spaces called "CompanyName". The CompanyName field contains things like, `"ABC Client", "BCD CLIENT 123", "EFG CLIENT HIJ"`

When I index the data I set the mapping to "index" : "not_analyzed". When I run an aggregation, without any other queries, it appears to work fine.

The issue I have is that if I want to first run another query and then get an aggregation of those results, the aggregation then breaks because it interprets the spaces in the company names, so it looks like the aggregation is run over the output of the first query and not over the field that I setup.

The query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "Stuff": "1"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "filename": "FileOfData.sourcedata"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "users": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "CompanyName"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have also tried adding a custom analyzer using:

```
"analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
      "companynamestring": {
        "type": "custom",
        "tokenizer": "keyword",
        "filter": "lowercase"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And it is still not working. Does anyone know how I can run a query and then get an aggregation that returns only the full CompanyName field and is not tokenized?

Thanks!

Comment: Posting the mapping would be helpful

Comment: Your mapping most likely is broken. If your field is truly `not_analyzed` then it should work.

Comment: Thanks, this was a mapping issue. I added a new mapping which is now working.